# Spring Integration inbound webservices wsdl generation

Tags: web-services, spring-integration, soapfault, inbound

I am trying to evaluate Spring Integration specially interested in exposing a simple POJO based service into a SOAP based  webservice via service activator. Currently I am stuck & have issue generating dynamic wsdl. The WSDL is not loaded & browser shows 404 error. 
I try to access with the following url on my local

```
http://localhost:8080/ws-inbound-gateway/echoService
http://localhost:8080/ws-inbound-gateway/echoService/echoService.wsdl
```

Below is the configuration

inbound-gateway-config.xml

```
<int:channel id="inbound" />

    <bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
        <property name="contextPath" value="com.manish.schema.generated" />
    </bean>

    <int-ws:inbound-gateway id="empServiceGateway"
        request-channel="inbound" marshaller="marshaller"
        unmarshaller="marshaller" />

    <int:service-activator input-channel="inbound"
        requires-reply="true" ref="employeeServiceActivator" method="getEmployeeDetails">

    </int:service-activator>

    <bean id="employeeServiceActivator"
        class="org.springframework.integration.samples.ws.EmployeeServiceResponder" />

    <bean id="employeeService" class="com.manish.service.EmployeeService" />
```

EmployeeService is just a pojo class while EmployeeServiceResponder is a service activator that invokes method on a service class.

For dynamic wsdl generation

spring-ws-config.xml

```
<import resource="classpath:/META-INF/spring/integration/inbound-gateway-config.xml" />

<sws:dynamic-wsdl id="echoService" portTypeName="empServiceGateway" locationUri="/echoService" targetNamespace="http://manish.niyati.com/echo">
    <sws:xsd location="/WEB-INF/echo.xsd"/>
</sws:dynamic-wsdl>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.UriEndpointMapping">
    <property name="defaultEndpoint" ref="empServiceGateway"></property>
</bean>
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/spring-ws-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>transformWsdlLocations</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/echoService</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Kindly let me know what else is missing in order to make this service accessible as web-service via SI.

Also when I try to access the service from using WebService template I get the SOAPFAULT

```
02:18:59.436 INFO  [main][org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory] Creating SAAJ 1.3 MessageFactory with SOAP 1.1 Protocol
02:18:59.437 DEBUG [main][org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory] Using MessageFactory class [com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl]
02:18:59.484 DEBUG [main][org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate] Opening [org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpUrlConnection@249fa95c] to [http://localhost:8080/ws-inbound-gateway/echoService]
02:18:59.519 TRACE [main][org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.support.SaajUtils] SOAPElement [com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.Envelope1_1Impl] implements SAAJ 1.3
02:18:59.535 TRACE [main][org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.support.SaajUtils] SOAPElement [com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.Body1_1Impl] implements SAAJ 1.3
02:18:59.562 TRACE [main][org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing.sent] Sent request [<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body><ed:employeeRequest xmlns:ed="http://manish.niyati.com/echo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> <ed:empid>100</ed:empid> </ed:employeeRequest></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>]
02:18:59.604 TRACE [main][org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing.received] Received response [<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body><SOAP-ENV:Fault><faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode><faultstring xml:lang="en">**java.lang.NullPointerException**</faultstring></SOAP-ENV:Fault></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>] for request [<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body><ed:employeeRequest xmlns:ed="http://manish.niyati.com/echo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> <ed:empid>100</ed:empid> </ed:employeeRequest></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>]
02:18:59.605 DEBUG [main][org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate] Received Fault message for request [SaajSoapMessage {http://manish.niyati.com/echo}employeeRequest]
02:18:59.607 TRACE [main][org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.support.SaajUtils] SOAPElement [com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.Fault1_1Impl] implements SAAJ 1.3
```

Thanks in Advance
-MS

Comment: Are you using any reference implementations? e.g. Apache cxf serves a great RI for developing web-services with spring configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the WSDL, change the web.xml url-pattern to `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`.

and the URL is `http://localhost:8080/ws-inbound-gateway/echoService.wsdl`.

Everything else looks good.

Regarding the WebServiceTemplateQuestion, what are you sending? It looks like you are using the ws sample app, which uses a WebServiceTemplate...

```
@Test
public void testWebServiceRequestAndResponse() {
    StringResult result = new StringResult();
    Source payload = new StringSource(
            "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
            "<echoRequest xmlns=\"http://www.springframework.org/spring-ws/samples/echo\">hello</echoRequest>");

    template.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(WS_URI, payload, result);
    logger.info("RESULT: " + result.toString());
    assertThat(result.toString(), equalTo(
            "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
            "<echoResponse xmlns=\"http://www.springframework.org/spring-ws/samples/echo\">hello</echoResponse>"));
}
```

And that works just fine.

Looks like your NPE is on the server - take a look at the server logs to see what happened.

Comment: Perfect... it is **fixed** now.. also resolved NPE.. that was due to incorrect autowiring.. Thanks Gary..

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it in a much more complex way. With a simple configuration and using some basic annotations, you can develop a web service in a short time.

I have myself used [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) for web service development and it is quite good for spring based configuration. You can also take a look at this [blog](http://angelozerr.wordpress.com/2011/08/24/jaxwscxf_step2/). It has shown all the steps with figures to develop a web service with the generation of wsdl and a client to consume the web service.

Comment: thanks for your replying, I have used spring ws earlier & have been able to develop ws smoothly.. but SI is a different approach for developing enterprise messaging.. through SI the application can be developed keeping in mind the various EIP. Messages can source from and destined to any source including file system, JMS, JPA, WS, REST, Socket, batch process, TCP, HTTP, RMI, JDBC etc..